# How to simulate a click on a full screen game with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, click

I am trying to simulate a click on a fullscreen game like shellshock.io or narrow.one (the one I am trying to do). How would I do this with javascript?

If possible, can you simulate a keypress on a game too?

Comment: Can you please provide some code you have written yourself? Please read here on how to provide a minimal, reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Please try following.

```html
<div class="fullScreenElement">
   ...
   <button id="elementYouWantToClick">Example</button>
   ...
</div>
```

```
document.getElementById('elementYouWantToClick').click(); // make sure this el is within the fullscreen element
```

Comment: Sorry, I am really new to coding, what is an EL?

Comment: @StarrySkies He is saying El is short for element. And EL id is the id in your HTML tag.